# Precedence in Spring Solr Query when using a list

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I am trying to get a Spring Solr query using a repository and implement the following

> findByXOrYAndZ

The precedence should be as follows:

> (X OR Y) AND Z

I am using a SolrCrudRepository:

```
Page<SolrX> findByXOrYAndZ(List<String> x, Boolean y, String z);
```

How can I enforce the precedence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Query` to do so.

```
@Query("(x:(?0) OR y:?1) AND z:?2")
Page<SolrX> findByXOrYAndZ(List<String> x, Boolean y, String z);
```

Comment: This causes a "undefined field text" from solr

Comment: Can you provide the query that was actually executed against solr from the solr server logs? Which solr version do you use?